# How to measure the tendency of a distribution to be closer to the extremes of a range?

Tags: performance, statistics, distribution

I have 1000 sets of simulated model results (generally skewed).

Each of those sets varies in a different range (e.g. [0.5,0.75], [0.01,0.9],...), however the possible outcomes are confined between 0 and 1 by the model configuration.

Is there a "measure", based on which I can find out if the set tends to be closer to 0 or closer to 1?

Answer (score 0):

How about using variance?  Variance measures the expected squared deviation from the center of gravity (the mean).  When values are far away from the mean, the variance is large, when values are close to the mean, the variance is small. For values that are uniformly distributed in the range (0,1), the variance is 1/12.  For non-uniform outcomes in the range (0,1) the maximum variance of 1/4 occurs when half of them are at 0 and the other half are at 1.  Values less than 1/12 indicate bunching towards the mean.

Based on this, I'd suggest calculating the sample variance of your sets.  Anything with an estimated variance greater than 1/12 is bunching towards the outside of the range.  The larger the variance, approaching 1/4, the more the outcomes are bunched towards the extremes of 0 and 1.

**ADDENDUM**

From your rewording and comment, you're not asking whether outcomes are spread more toward both edges or toward the center, you're asking if outcomes tend to clump towards the ends of the range.  Variances are measures of spread (hence my earlier suggestion), while means or medians are measures of location.  Calculate the sample mean (average) or median of your sets, and see if they are around 1/2, closer to 0, or closer to 1.  Discrepancies between the average and median will give an indication of how symmetric or skewed the sets are.

Comment: Thanks for your answer pjs! However your approach doesn't distinguish between the case in which the set tends to 0 and the case in which it tends to 1...My fault, I have to edit my question to make this clear. Any idea?